# How to fix error code P1000 for Ford F-150 with engine 4.6L of year 2006

Tags: ford, f-150

Make: Ford

Model: F-150

Engine: P1000

Year: 2006

Error codes: 4.6L

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

On Fords a p1000 code is a system not ready code. Meaning the truck hasn't passed all emissions monitors. Drive it some more and the code will go away. The code comes up when the computer is reset or the battery has been disconnected without an external power source for the computer.